# Lazy-loading for React Native ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, lazy-loading

Currently, my React Native app contains many complex components rendered in ScrollView. I'll use the following method to optimize the render for ScrollView:

- Track the current location of the ScrollView offset.
- Check if the component's position in ScrollView is being viewed, then render Component or render skeleton component

Do you think this will improve the ScrollView's optimization? How can I keep an eye on if it performs better?

Comment: Please provide some details of code what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't, since you will have to cause a re-render to update the scroll view rendered components.

I don't know what you mean by **many complex components**, but if there are many you should use **FlatList/SectionList**. There are libraries that provide a better performance while working with lists.

https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/

https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

If some logic is triggered inside your ScrollView items when rendered, e.g., UseEffecs / Queries / Fetching Image etc ...

You can implement

1. [onViewableItemsChanged](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onviewableitemschanged)
2. [viewabilityConfig](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#viewabilityconfig)

Then using **forwardRef** and **useImperativeHandle** you can assign the logic to the ref and trigger it whenever a particular item is visible or about to become visible.

It is not a simple solution, but in a nutshell this is the way to optimize a list in react-native

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. In my situation, the elements displayed in the scroll view are not same, hence I find it difficult to utilize flatlist; it functions more like a landing page.

But as you mention using a ref, I realize that it will be more optimized than my way.